# Вывод из скрипта javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Существует вот такой javascript, который при нажатии на кнопку checkboxa выводит определенный текст:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio[id=cb1]').change(function(){
  var ddd = $(this).val();
    if (ddd == 'Поддерживающая' || ddd == 'Генеральная' || ddd == 'После ремонта')
    {
        $("input[name=fullprice]").val("Сообщение1!");
    }
});
});/*end  ready*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio[id=cb2]').change(function(){
  var ddd = $(this).val();
    if (ddd == 'Поддерживающая' || ddd == 'Генеральная' || ddd == 'После ремонта')
    {
        $("input[name=fullprice]").val("Сообщение2!");
    }
});
});/*end  ready*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio[id=cb3]').change(function(){
  var ddd = $(this).val();
    if (ddd == 'Поддерживающая' || ddd == 'Генеральная' || ddd == 'После ремонта')
    {
        $("input[name=fullprice]").val("Сообщение3!");
    }
});
});/*end  ready*/
</script>


<form action="send_mail.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">


<h2>Три пункта checkbox:</p>
<input type="radio" name="check[]" value = "Поддерживающая" id = "cb1" />
<label for="cb1">Поддерживающая</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="check[]" value = "Генеральная" id = "cb2" />
<label for="cb2">Генеральная</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="check[]" value = "После ремонта" id = "cb3"/>
<label for="cb3">После ремонта</label> <br>
<h2><input type="text" size="4" name="fullprice" value="" readonly style = "width:600px"><br></h2>
<br>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что это сообщение нормально выводится на компьютерах, но на мобильных телефонах оно выезжает за пределы окна. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что значит _выезжает за пределы окна_?

Comment: `style = "width:600px"` у тебя жестко установлена ширина поля ввода. Если экран будет иметь ширину меньше - то чуть будет не видна

Comment: У вас ширина слишком большая стоит для мобильных устройств (600xp)

Comment: Задай `max-width: 100%;` И у вас в `head` написано `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`